# How to start Phoenix server when you are already in iex?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I know we can launch iex -S mix phoenix.server. But say I am already in iex -S mix. What can I do to get the server started?

Thank you.

Comment: I would open another terminal and then start the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's maybe not a great way of doing it, but I'm imagining you're only doing this in dev anyway. But one way of doing it would be to set the [same config option](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/385bdebdcc879dfb06f02faa5bef7d5e0b97761c/lib/mix/tasks/phx.server.ex#L34) `mix phx.server` sets then restarting your endpoint (this example stops it and lets the app supervisor restart it).

```rb
iex> Application.put_env(:phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true)
:ok
iex> GenServer.stop(MyAppWeb.Endpoint)
:ok
[info] Running MyAppWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.9.0 at 0.0.0.0:4000 (http)
```

Comment: The only answer that understood the issue and directly addressed it with understanding! I tested it and it works.  Thank you @BrettBeatty.

Answer (score 2):

Just start running as `iex -S mix phx.server`, then both `iex` and your application will run together

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Sometimes I already have stuff set up in iex and I don't want to restart. Perhaps I should have been clearer.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry to tell you that this cannot be done.

See this discussion for reference: https://elixirforum.com/t/mix-task-run-deps-compile-dep-name-force-not-compiling/12114/4

I quote:

> Mix is not intended to be called from iex or inside of your application. The primary interface is the CLI and because of this tasks are allowed to only run once.

Comment: I tried Brett's solution and it works. If you disagree, or think it is incomplete, please let us know. Thank you Peaceful James for your effort in answering.